# phpexcel export selected sheet to pdf

Tags: php, phpexcel, mpdf

I have an xlsx file with 4 Sheets. Using the code below I am able to export the first sheet only.

I want to be able to export any sheet **by name** to pdf.

Below is what I've done so far:

```
    $export_file = 'export.pdf';

    $import_file = './media/migration/import.xlsx';

    $sheet_name = 'Menu_A';

    $rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF;

    $rendererLibraryPath = '/var/www/public/vendor/mpdf/mpdf';

    $object = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($import_file);

    $object->setActiveSheetIndexByName($sheet_name);

    PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer($rendererName, $rendererLibraryPath);

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($object, 'PDF');

    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $export_file . '"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: probably have to loop though the sheets

Comment: @nogad what if I have too many sheets.

Comment: not sure you can have "to many" sheets. if you want 1 pdf, you should combine the data first. for multiple pdfs (you cant send them to the browser) just keep looping

Comment: @nogad I have many sheets inside the excel file and I just want to export one of them to pdf. I want to select that one by name or index, not loop through till I hit it.

Comment: then i dont see the porblem. you have `$sheet_name = 'Menu_A';` in the code above, just change it as needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, only the first worksheet will be generated for html/pdf output unless you tell the Writer which sheet to display before saving:

```
$objWriter->setSheetIndex(1);
```

(for the second sheet)

```
$objWriter->setSheetIndex($object->getActiveSheetIndex());
```

(for the current active worksheet)

```
$objWriter->setSheetIndex($object->getIndex($object->getSheetByName($sheet_name)));
```

(for a named worksheet)